# Making the same changes, made in data set A, to data set B

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset `datA` which is a sample of the population. In that sample, some groups are too small, so they have to be added together. Because the sample needs to be weighted (sample/pop), these changes have to be made in the population as well.  The issue is that simply applying the same code to `datB` does not work, because there are enough observations in the population.

## Example data

I have example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
datA <- fread("
NA,0,2,NA,cat X, type 1
3,4,3,1,cat X, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat X, type 3
3,4,3,0,cat X, type 4
NA,0,2,NA,cat Y, type 1
NA,4,3,NA,cat Y, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat Y, type 3
3,4,3,35,cat Y, type 4
NA,0,2,NA,cat X, type 1
3,4,3,1,cat X, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat X, type 3
NA,4,3,NA,cat X, type 4
NA,0,2,NA,cat Y, type 1
NA,4,3,NA,cat Y, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat Y, type 3
3,4,3,1,cat Y, type 4
1,0,2,4,cat X, type 1
3,4,3,1,cat X, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat X, type 3
3,4,3,2,cat X, type 4
NA,0,2,NA,cat Y, type 1
NA,4,3,NA,cat Y, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat Y, type 3
3,4,3,2,cat Y, type 4
")

names(datA) <- c("A","B","C", "D", "cat", "type")
```

## Changes made to sample/datA

```
observations_grp <- function(x) {
  cumsum_i <- 0
  nxtgrp <-  F
  n <- length(x)
  grp <- rep(0,n)
  grp_i <- 0;
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (nxtgrp) {grp_i <- grp_i + 1; cumsum_i <- 0;}
    nxtgrp <- !((cumsum_i + x[i]) < 2)
    cumsum_i <- cumsum_i + x[i]
    grp[i] <- grp_i
  }
  grp
}

datA <- datA[, observations_D := sum(!is.na(D)), by = c("cat", "type")]
datA <- datA[, new_type := type]
datA[,`:=`(new_type = last(new_type), observations_D =sum(observations_D)),
        .(cat,observations_grp(observations_D))
][]
```

I can get the rows that have been changed out by doing the following:

```
changed_rows <- datA[type!=new_type]
```

## Making the same changes in the population/datB

Now I want to make these type changes to a different dataset, with a similar structure, but a different amount of rows, the population data represented by `datB`:

```
datB <- cbind(datA, datA)
```

I would like to use the information from `changed_rows` to make changes in `pop_dat`. Something like:

if the `cat` of `changed_rows` is equal to  `cat` of `pop_dat`, change the `type` in `changed_rows` to the new `type` from `changed_rows`.

```
setDT(datB)[datB$cat==changed_rows$cat, new_type:=changed_rows$new_type]
```

I have no idea how to write this syntax however. Could someone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data frame describing the type changes you computed:

```r
type_changes <- unique(changed_rows[, .(cat, type, new_type)])
type_changes
#>      cat   type new_type
#> 1: cat X type 1   type 2
#> 2: cat Y type 1   type 3
#> 3: cat Y type 2   type 3
```

Then apply them to the other data frame with an update join:

```r
datB <- rbind(datA, datA)[, 1:6]
head(datB)
#>     A B C  D   cat   type
#> 1: NA 0 2 NA cat X type 1
#> 2:  3 4 3  1 cat X type 2
#> 3:  1 0 2  2 cat X type 3
#> 4:  3 4 3  0 cat X type 4
#> 5: NA 0 2 NA cat Y type 1
#> 6: NA 4 3 NA cat Y type 2

datB[type_changes, type := new_type, on = .(cat, type)]
head(datB)
#>     A B C  D   cat   type
#> 1: NA 0 2 NA cat X type 2
#> 2:  3 4 3  1 cat X type 2
#> 3:  1 0 2  2 cat X type 3
#> 4:  3 4 3  0 cat X type 4
#> 5: NA 0 2 NA cat Y type 3
#> 6: NA 4 3 NA cat Y type 3
```